# LINQ to SQL -DAL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I wish to Implement LINQ-to-SQL as my Data Access Layer. I am using SQL Server. Is there 
any Linq-to-SQL framework (commercial or open source) available that can function like 
Application Block (caching block, validation, etc..)?

Comment: I'm just curious, why not use Linq to Entity Framework in the upcoming v4?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide a Linq to SQL framework.  There are plenty of articles about it in the web, e.g.

[LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)

[Using LINQ to SQL (Part 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)